# If I parallel a 0 Ohm wire with another 0 Ohm wire conducting current in a circuit, what would the equivalent resistance of the two 0 Ohm wires be?

Tags: resistors, parallel

And what is the current distribution of each wire?
I am wondering this question because the formula of paralleled resistance yields an undefined answer of 0/0.

Comment: A 0 ohm in parallel with any other resistor is still 0 ohm.

Comment: It will be 0/2 Ohm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as an actual 0Ω wire in reality unless you are talking about superconductors. If you look at the effect

R= R1*R2/(R1+R2), as both R1 and R2 grow arbitrarily small, say \$\sigma\$, the parallel resistance will be \$\sigma/2\$ so it will approach zero as well.

In the case of actual superconductors, the current split will come down to effects such as inductance, but the resistance will always be exactly zero.

Comment: *"superconductors will behave like ideal inductors"* From here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/192641/current-splitting-in-the-presence-of-superconductors.

Comment: Your 2nd paragraph captures the essence without introducing exotic ideas. Simple and direct. +1 Assume \$R=R_1=R_2\$ (by question definition this is true.) Then \$\frac{R_1 \,R_2}{R_1+R_2}=\frac{R^2}{2\,R}=\frac12R\$. So \$R\to0\$ yields the intuitive result.

Answer (score 3):

Don't waste your time with resistance. Flip it to conductance.

A zero ohm resistor has infinity conductance.

When paralleled, conductance simply adds. Therefore the conductance of the parallels is double infinity.

Current distribution is proportional to the conductances. Infinity is a slippery concept but it appears to me current would split evenly across each parallel.

Flipping back to resistance, we see that a resistor of double infinity conductance is zero ohms.

By the way, it doesn't matter with zero and infinity, but if you ever want to do real math with it, the conductance unit is the *siemens* or capital S.   So 0.25 ohm = 4.0 S.  They are one and the same, even if one expression gets all the press :)

Comment: The assumption that the current splits evenly is not justified. In the theoretical world of circuit theory, you'd have an undetermined matrix if you tried to solve the circuit using nodal or mesh analysis. There would be an infinity of valid solutions. For a 1 A total current it might be 0.5 A in each branch or 0.1 in one and 0.9 in the other or -100 A in one and 101 A in the other.

Comment: In a real physical circuit the balance of currents might be determined by details not modeled (contact resistance, ...), by the inductance of the different branches and the dynamics when the circuit was turnedon; or by stray magnetic fields through the circuit (something deliberately ignored when we apply the lumped circuit approximation of everyday circuit theory)

Comment: @Photon well that's the trouble with infinity.  I would say "equal resistance equal current" but you'd say "one infinity is not necessarily equal to the other" and everyone's right and wrong at the same time lol.  Now all we need is a cat!

Answer (score 1):

Two "no resistances" in parallel would just be same as one "no resistance" so still 0 ohms.

It does not lead to 0/0 if you think in limits, like 1/R units.

When R approaches 0, 1/R approaches infinity. Therefore, adding up two of those still approach infinity. When you convert it back to resistances, you have a single item that approaches zero.

Another way to look at is that even if one resistance is zero, then for all currents from zero to infinity, there will be zero volts over zero resistance, so there will also be zero volts over the other resistor, so the resistance is irrelevant as for any non-zero resistance there will be no current through it, so effective resistance is the zero and the other has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Zero ohm resistors can only be approximated. They are considered 0\$\Omega\$ only if the actual resistance is insignificant compared to the nearby impedances connected to it.

Zero ohm resistors do have a range of values, but no matter how small that the range is the percentage uncertainty will always be infinite. So it is impossible to say how the current is distributed when two are connected in parallel.

Trying to pin down zero should always start with values not equal to zero, then comparisons are made to determine whether their contributions are insignificant enough to say R=0.

> the formula of paralleled resistance yields an undefined answer of 0/0.

The answer is in the question. 0/0 is indeterminate in that it can be anything. So to make sense, small values must be assumed. Then a calculation can be made. Zero ohm resistors do come with a maximum resistance value plus/minus. You can use these values to estimate how two zero ohm resistors in parallel might behave.